# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS thrown while validating json schema through json schema validator

Tags: json, validation, jackson, schema

I am new to RestAPI testing. I am trying to use Jsonschemavalidor. I added the jar file and all the dependencies. Still I get following error. Can anyone give solution to the problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit>(JsonInclude.java:205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:45)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:543)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:460)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JacksonUtils.newMapper(JacksonUtils.java:155)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JacksonUtils.<clinit>(JacksonUtils.java:55)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonNodeReader.<init>(JsonNodeReader.java:82)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.<clinit>(JsonLoader.java:50)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$4.createJsonNodeInstance(JsonSchemaValidator.java:164)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$4.createJsonNodeInstance(JsonSchemaValidator.java:161)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$JsonSchemaValidatorFactory.create(JsonSchemaValidator.java:254)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema(JsonSchemaValidator.java:161)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(JsonSchemaValidator.java:117)
    at com.nasdaq.api.GenericLib.validateJsonSchema(GenericLib.java:441)
```

Answer (score 16):

Did you add the latest version of jackson-annotations? The [`USE_DEFAULTS`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#USE_DEFAULTS) enum constant was added in 2.6:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I added the latest and  that resolved the problem.

Comment: @user3419588 - if you could mark this answer as accepted, it would help others find the solution who have a similar problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Add it according to this in `pom.xml` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.6.0